# Why am I getting a syntax error when I pass a coderef to this prototyped Perl subroutine?

Tags: perl, reference, coderef

This is the code:

```
sub function($&) {
    my $param1 = shift;
    my $code = shift;
    # do something with $param1 and $code
}
```

If I try to call it like this:

```
function("whatever") {
    print "i'm inside the coderef\n";
}
```

I get `Not enough arguments for MyPackage::function at x.pl line 5, near ""whatever" { "`. How can I call it without having to add `sub` in front of the code block?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Put the coderef argument first:

```
sub function (&$) {
    my $code = shift;
    my $param1 = shift;
    # do something with $param1 and $code
}

function { print "i'm inside the coderef\n" } "whatever";
```

See the perlsub man page, which reads in part:

> An "&" requires an anonymous subroutine, which, if passed as the first argument, 
> does not require the "sub" keyword or a subsequent comma.

Comment: @Geo, it can work, but you need to be more explicit: `function( "whatever", sub { print "I'm inside the coderef\n" } );` The `name BLOCK EXPR` syntax only works if the coderef comes first.

Comment: Only because it was designed that way.  I suspect the main reason for allowing it in the first place was to let users write subroutines that can be called like built-in functions that take a small snippet of code like map and grep, but anything more flexible could probably get confusing fast.

Comment: And it's something folks are working on.  http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PerlX::MethodCallWithBlock

Comment: One reason why it would be problematic to have a block as a final argument is this: the parser expects an operator, not a term. There are some situations where two terms in a row are allowed, but they are difficulties for the parser.

Comment: @Robert P => so now Perl can backport syntactic anomalies from Ruby :-/

Comment: It's **Science!**  Of course, with 5.12's parser hooks, it's going to be possible to do oh, so much more.

Comment: @Robert P => sounds interesting, do you have any links that describe the new hooks?

Comment: Sure do!  Check out the 5.12 Perl Delta ( http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perl5120delta ) document.

Answer (score -3):

Here,
$& is a Perl's special variable which is used to match the exact pattern. (you have wrongly used it in your context)
$` is used to match the string before the given pattern.
$' is used to match the string after the given pattern.

Comment: In the context in which the OP uses it, it's a function prototype. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes